# Suction and discharge heights

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The following is a diagram from my Fluid Mechanics module's lecture slides:

[image]

The topic is Fluid Machinery where the focus is on studying pumps. My question is on the suction and discharge heights depicted in this diagram. The heights depicted seem rather arbitrary/random. For example, the height on the left does not even reach the upper reservoir. Shouldn't the height be the whole height from the pump's height level to the surface of the water in the tank?

Answer (score 0):

The heights are those of the location of the pressure gauges, and so are relevent when you are using  the readings on those gauges to compute the change in pressure between  the input and output sides of the pump..